# Is it OK to omit CSS Grid areas you have defined?

Tags: php, html, css, css-grid

Do you think it's acceptable to omit grid areas you've defined from your markup? I have defined the following `grid-template-areas` but deliberately omitted them:

```
grid-template-areas: "nav  one two three"
"nav  four five six";
```

I assigned one grid area, the `nav` so that I could get two columns, but the rest of the grid areas are populated in PHP using a `foreach` loop, and it seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Here's a CodePen to demonstrate:

https://codepen.io/endymion1818/pen/LOOJoy

Since this works for the layout I want to achieve, and allows the client to add more blocks if they want to without breaking the layout, should I use it in production?

Comment: This question is not entirely clear. You're saying you want `grid-template-areas` to be fully coded, but the HTML won't appear until later (when the loop runs)?

Comment: Hi Michael_B, sorry for the delay in replying. Nope, nothing to do with the PHP, I merely wanted to know more about `grid-template-areas` and whether I could skip definitions. It's working, and thoroughly cross-browser tested, so I'm going to ship it and see what happens!